# Passing other variables in my view's edit form

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have this code right here :

```
<td class="nowrap has-context">
        <a href="<?php 
    echo JRoute::_('index.php option=com_subscription&task=subscriptionsform.edit&reportId='.$this->escape($item['id'])); ?>">
            <?php echo $this->escape($item['title']); ?>
            </td>
```

I am trying to pass the variable reportId in my Edit view but when I click the link, the reportId is not found. Are there any restrictions in passing variables to the edit form? is it only restricted on an Item's Id which is the default?

```
http://localhost/bdes3/index.php/component/subscription/subscriptionsform?layout=edit
```

it always redirects to this link. When I removed
    $controller->redirect(); in my main controller, the reportId was included in the URL but the edit fields were gone.

Comment: What do you get if you `echo $this->escape($item['id']);` ? Does the ID actually appear?

Comment: When I include the Id as a column in the list, the Id appears correct. It's when I pass it as a parameter to the edit view that it disappears.

Comment: Try checking your controller for a function called `edit`...you might find a redirect occurring there.

Comment: GDP it worked but unfortunately the edit form fields was gone. it only displayed a blank page.

Comment: Not sure what "worked", but if a redirect is there, it may not be including your reportId, thus not appearing where you would expect.  I don't know the component, so can't guide you any further other than that hint/suggestion.

Comment: In my controller file 'subscription.php' ,i removed this

    $controller->redirect();

then the url displayed:

index.php?option=com_subscription&view=subscriptionsform&layout=edit&reportId=2 but the fields for editing were gone.
 is this the correct one? or the one in my controller/subscriptions.php

by the way this is a custom component I am developing

Comment: innocent mistake. I was editing the wrong controller file. I was able to get the variable I passed now. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honest mistake. I was editing the wrong controller file. It should be the controller/subscriptionsform.php not subscriptions.php